# Sbt do not update snapshot in Local maven repo

Tags: maven, sbt

I have a project that is based on maven, and in which I am integrating some libraries that I am developing in Scala using SBT.

Currently the SBT project (in which I am developing the Lib) has a snapshot version.

While the snapshot jar is well updated in Ivy correctly it is not the case in Maven when I use PublishM2. I have to delete the previous one to get to have the new version that I would publish with PublishM2.

Is there a way to ensure that my PublishM2 update the local Maven repository properly (meaning with a new snapshot)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following sbt command:

```
sbt publishLocal publishM2
```

It should publish artifact into local Maven repository.